# How can I measure CPU and RAM used by my theme or plugin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, testing

I have produced a few plugins for WordPress, but other than generating errors, I don´t have a way to tell if my plugin is doing things right.

How can I tell the ammount of CPU time and RAM my plugins use?

I know it´s a second question, but it´s related: How does one test the software other than browsing as a user?

Comment: what do you mean **How does one test the software other than browsing as a user?**

Comment: I mean I did not go to programmer university, so I don´t know the proper ways to test a software. When I build a plugin, I turn on wp_debug and check for errors while I do what a user would. Is there another way to test a plugin?

Comment: There's no such thing as mandatory to go to *programmer university*,to be good at what you do. however I found few resources, check them out. [here](https://upstreamplugin.com/plugintests/) and  [here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/test-wordpress-plugins-addendio/) and  [here](https://asphaltthemes.com/alternative-to-p3-plugin-performance-profiler/) and  [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-check-for-plugin-memory-usage/)

Comment: The proper way of doing this would be to **add tests to your plugins**. See https://upstreamplugin.com/plugintests/ and https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/plugin-unit-tests/ and https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/automated-testing-wordpress-plugins-phpunit/.

Answer (score 0):

I kept on researching and this is the best I've found and have been doing so far:

1. Enable all logs on settings and wp-config: [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).
2. Install the following plugins for developers. You can learn about them and how they can help you by going to the respective's plugin page:

   - [UsageDD](https://wordpress.org/plugins/usagedd/) - TTFB, queries and RAM. Super light weight. Must have.
   - [Error Log Viewer by BestWebSoft](https://wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-viewer/) - See all log files in your install directory Log
   - [Log Deprecated Notices](https://wordpress.org/plugins/log-deprecated-notices/) - To see what other logs won't show

Should I find more or if anyone has anything to add, we can edit the answer for future new WordPress developers.